# How to convert USB Joystick Gamepad data output to angle

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, joystick

I'm currently working on a home automation project with raspberry pi 3 and Python. The goal for me is to control motor servos from a Thrustmaster T16000M USB Joystick but I'm stuck to "convert" the joystick values to angles in degrees.

For example, the X axis goes from 0 to 16383. But I would like to convert this to go from 0° to 180°. My problem is the mapping between the angle values in degrees and the Joystick values. I have the impression that I have to use lists with a "cursor" that determines for example: 0° = 0 for the Joytick, 90° = 8192 for the Joystick, 180° = 16383.

I can understand the logic but the implementation is more complicated because I don't know if it's the right method, and especially if it is possible.

I also looked at vectors, matrices etc., but after a day of working on it, I was able to understand the logic but the implementation is more complicated because I don't know if it's the right method, and especially if it's possible. I'm a bit confused about how to do it.

Comment: What is the range for the y values? For both the x and y axes, are the readings for each ½ way between the minimum and maximum when the joystick is straight-up (vertical)?

Comment: Yes exactly.

The value of the Y and X axis varies from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 16383.

When the Joystick is in normal position, X and Y are 8191. Left X = 0, Y = 8191. On the right, X = 16383 and Y = 8191. Vice versa depending on the axis used.

Comment: Just mapping the range of values to 0..180 isn't quite the same as converting the x & y position _togetehre_ into an angle — which I think is what one would want if trying to measure the angle they represent considering the top side of the controller (x=8191, y=16383) to be 0° North. Doing this would involve do some relatively simple trigonometry — [`math.atan2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2) I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question, this should be very easy.

```
x_max = 16383
output_max = 180

# Assume x is an arbitrary value between 0 and x_max
output = x / x_max * output_max
```

That's it. Output will be a mapping of your x value between 0 and 16383 to a scale from 0 to 180.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my problem! I have just tested this and I get the angle value back well. Thank you very much for this very fast and correct answer. Indeed the solution is not very difficult, I don't understand why I looked for complicated where it shouldn't have been.

Thank you very much for your help :)